# Import data from Google Checkout into Quickbooks?

Tags: quickbooks, google-checkout

Is there any way to import data from Google Checkout into Quickbooks? (Or another accounting package)?

Answer (score 3):

Yep - you can export CSV from Google and import that into Quickbooks (and presumably into other accounting packages):

[Google Checkout - Reporting and reconciliation](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134476&topic=8951)

[QuickBooks - Tools for importing Excel and CSV files](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Pages/KnowledgeBaseArticle/1005472)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the QuickBooks SDK to build an integrated application that could automatically push data into QuickBooks.

You can use the Google Checkout API to suck data out, and then QuickBooks SDK qbXML requests to push data into QuickBooks. You could automate it/schedule it so you don't have to do manual CSV imports everyday.

[QuickBooks SDK](http://developer.intuit.com/)

[QuickBooks Web Connector](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/)

[Open-source QuickBooks PHP framework](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=9164)

[Open-source QuickBooks .NET framework](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=11040&enterthread=y)

[QuickBooks and Ruby](http://qbruby.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a site http://www.ktsolutionsllc.com that states to have a integration component that integrates google checkout and quickbooks.  I would give that a try!

Thanks.